# Relationship between two power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** If $f(z) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty a_n z^n$, what is $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n$ ?

I can prove the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n$ will be same of the power series of the function $f(z)$. But I am not getting any relationship with $f(z)$ and the function where the power series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n$ converges. Is there any relationship between $f(z)$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: Take derivative and multiply by $z$. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Compute the first derivative of f(z) and multiply the result by z. Compute the second derivative of f(z) and multiply the result by z^2 and so on.

Comment: @PeterKošinár. You won by less than a second ! Cheers and Happy New Year !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can express $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3a_n z^n$ using $f,f',f'',f'''$. Just find $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$n^3=a+bn+cn(n-1)+dn(n-1)(n-2)$$
and you have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3a_n z^n=af(z)+bzf'(z)+cz^2f''(z)+dz^3f'''(z)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After completing the calculation I am getting $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $c = 3$, $d = 1$. Nice!